# Question about foreign-key relationship in Linq to Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have lots of tables and some of them have many relationships with other tables. I noticed the tables that have one relationship I am able to do what it is shown in NerdDinner Chapter 1.

```
Dinner dinner = db.Dinners.Single(d => d.DinnerID == 1);
RSVP myRSVP = new RSVP();
myRSVP.AttendeeName = "ScottGu";

dinner.RSVPs.Add(myRSVP);
```

So when I try something similar .add never shows up for me unless it has like one relationship.

So how do I make it work for multiple ones?

I am still not clear what this gets me anyways. Like does it save in typing? or what?

Comment: Be sure to check out Scott Guthrie's Linq to SQL tutorial at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, let's try to make this a bit clearer: here's the basic NerdDinner schema as you mention it in your post:

[image]

The question whether or not you'll have a "RSVPs" style property (a "EntitySet") to which you can add entities doesn't depend on the fact whether or not you have one or multiple relationships - it depends on which end of the relationship you're on.

The **parent table** (here: Dinner) has typically 0, 1, or more child entries in the **child table** (here: RSVP).

So in the parent table, you'll have to have a property "RSVPs" that allows you to store multiple entities - an **EntitySet**.

From the child table, however, the child can only ever be associated with exactly **one parent** - therefore, you only have a single Entity called "Dinner" (the dinner this RSVP is intended for).

You see that clearly when you click on the line between the two entities and look at its properties:

[image]

The "Cardinality" One-To-Many defines just this: a parent has many children, but a child has only exactly one parent.

Therefore, in your code, you'll be able to write this:

```
        NerdDinnerDataContext ctx = new NerdDinnerDataContext();

        Dinner upcomingDinner = new Dinner();
        upcomingDinner.EventDate = new DateTime(2009, 10, 10);
        upcomingDinner.Address = "One Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA";
        upcomingDinner.ContactPhone = "(555) 123 1234";

        upcomingDinner.RSVPs.Add(new RSVP() { AttendeeName = "ScottGu" });
        upcomingDinner.RSVPs.Add(new RSVP() { AttendeeName = "ScottHa" });
        upcomingDinner.RSVPs.Add(new RSVP() { AttendeeName = "PhilHa" });


        RSVP scottHunter = new RSVP();
        scottHunter.AttendeeName = "Scott Hunter";
        scottHunter.Dinner = upcomingDinner;
```

The parent (Dinner) has a collection of RSVPs (an EntitySet, to be exact, in Linq-to-SQL terminology), therefore you can have

```
        upcomingDinner.RSVPs.Add(new RSVP() { AttendeeName = "ScottGu" });
```

On the other hand, the child property "RSVP" can only be associated with exactly one Dinner, so it doesn't have an EntitySet, but just a single instance of a "Dinner" to establish the connection, and you'll write:

```
        scottHunter.Dinner = upcomingDinner;
```

Does that makes things a bit clearer? It's really the basics of relational database modelling and how to associate parent and child tables to one another - translated by Linq-to-SQL into objects and how they can be connected and associated.

Marc

Comment: single relation ship entity? Not sure what that is but I think I have some 0.1 relationships. How do I tell though. the diagram in mssql 2005 just show primary keys or 1 to many.

Comment: I think I am getting it more now. Now with RSVPs you don't have to add the DinnerId. I am not 100% sure about the last couple lines especially with scottHunter.Dinner = upcomingDinner;. Why would you put all those people who are being RSVP into a RSVP person? Or would this make a Dinner object and add "Scott Hunter" as the hosted by and fill in some other fields.

Comment: ASsigning the "Dinner" to "ScottHunter" will assign this dinner as the dinner ScottHunter plans to attend. It will establish an association between ScottHunter and the "upcomingDinner". From the "upcomingDinner", you'll now see a new "RSVP" object in its "RSVPs" EntitySet, called ScottHunter - he's been added to the list of attendees. From the ScottHunter RSVP object, you'll see the "UpcomingDinner" as the associated dinner he plans to attend. It's always a two-way association!

Answer (score 0):

You need one add for each table in the relationship.

The Add method stages an object into the Linq to SQL data context, so that it can be added to its corresponding database table.  The SubmitChanges method saves any pending changes to the database.  So you can do all of your adds, and then commit them at once.

Comment: Can you give an example please. I am not following I been doing sql to linq for like 5 mins now lol. So I don't know how to make these add methods and still not 100% clear on them.